# converting has_many and :belongs_to with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a current association where:

`Group :has_many Employees` and `Employee :belongs_to Group`

but now I want an Employee to be associated to many Groups as well.

For this purpose I am thinking of making:

`groupizations group_id:integer employee_id:integer created_at:datetime`

This will change Employee and Group models:

```
class Groupizations < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to  :employee
   belongs_to  :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many    :groupizations
   has_many    :employees, :through => categorizaitons
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many    :groupizations
   has_many    :groups, :through => categorizaitons
end
```

I understand all of this from [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) on Many-to-Many.  Only thing I am confused about is that right now I create a new Employee with following code:

```
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
    if @employee.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created employee."
      redirect_to @employee
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

how will this code change? Do I need to add data into `groupizations` at the same time now?

Comment: My (limited) understanding is that you don't need an intermediary Groupizations model unless you want extra data associated with each "groupization". You should be able to do HABTM without `:through`.

Comment: at a later stage other that might be the case. that is why I went with *zations approach.  I'm just unsure about how adding data will work now.

Comment: As `has_and_belongs_to_many` suffers from many limitations, it's best to avoid it and use the more modern `:through` method. The join model is light-weight and is generally never accessed directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an Employee to a Group, you would only need to do:

```
@employee.groups << @group
```

The `Groupization` record, as you've called it, will be created automatically. If you want to put some meta-data in the association, which is common when you want to specify the nature of this relationship, you could do something more formal:

```
@employee.groupizations.create(
  :group => group,
  :badge_number => 'F920'
)
```

As join models typically have a unique index on the two ID columns, be sure to rescue from errors that may occur when inserting a duplicate record. These look different depending on your back-end DB, so test accordingly. You can use `find_or_create` as needed.